# Decomposing a rotation matrix

Tags: direct3d, trigonometry

I have a rotation matrix. How can I get the rotation around a specified axis contained within this matrix?

Edit:

It's a 3D matrix (4x4), and I want to know how far around a predetermined (not contained) axis the matrix rotates. I can already decompose the matrix but D3DX will only give the entire matrix as one rotation around one axis, whereas I need to split the matrix up into angle of rotation around an already-known axis, and the rest.

Sample code and brief problem description:

```
D3DXMATRIX CameraRotationMatrix;
D3DXVECTOR3 CameraPosition;
//D3DXVECTOR3 CameraRotation;

inline D3DXMATRIX GetRotationMatrix() {
    return CameraRotationMatrix;
}
inline void TranslateCamera(float x, float y, float z) {
    D3DXVECTOR3 rvec, vec(x, y, z);
#pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&rvec, &vec, &GetRotationMatrix());
#pragma warning(default : 4238)
    CameraPosition += rvec;
    RecomputeVPMatrix();
}
inline void RotateCamera(float x, float y, float z) {
    D3DXVECTOR3 RotationRequested(x, y, z);
    D3DXVECTOR3 XAxis, YAxis, ZAxis;
    D3DXMATRIX rotationx, rotationy, rotationz;
    XAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(1, 0, 0);
    YAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0, 1, 0);
    ZAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 1);

#pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&XAxis, &XAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&YAxis, &YAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&ZAxis, &ZAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
#pragma warning(default : 4238)
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationx);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationy);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationz);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationx, &XAxis, RotationRequested.x);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationy, &YAxis, RotationRequested.y);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationz, &ZAxis, RotationRequested.z);
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationz;
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationy;
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationx;
    RecomputeVPMatrix();
}
inline void RecomputeVPMatrix() {
    D3DXMATRIX ProjectionMatrix;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
        &ProjectionMatrix,
        FoV,
        (float)D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferWidth / (float)D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferHeight,
        FarPlane,
        NearPlane
    );

    D3DXVECTOR3 CamLookAt;
    D3DXVECTOR3 CamUpVec;

#pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&CamLookAt, &D3DXVECTOR3(1, 0, 0), &GetRotationMatrix());
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&CamUpVec, &D3DXVECTOR3(0, 1, 0), &GetRotationMatrix());
#pragma warning(default : 4238)

    D3DXMATRIX ViewMatrix;
#pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&ViewMatrix, &CameraPosition, &(CamLookAt + CameraPosition), &CamUpVec);
#pragma warning(default : 4238)
    ViewProjectionMatrix = ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix;
    D3DVIEWPORT9 vp = {
        0,
        0,
        D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferWidth,
        D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferHeight,
        0,
        1
    };
    D3DDev->SetViewport(&vp);
}
```

Effectively, after a certain time, when RotateCamera is called, it begins to rotate in the relative X axis- even though constant zero is passed in for that request when responding to mouse input, so I know that when moving the mouse, the camera should not roll at all. I tried spamming 0,0,0 requests and saw no change (one per frame at 1500 frames per second), so I'm fairly sure that I'm not seeing FP error or matrix accumulation error. I tried writing a RotateCameraYZ function and stripping all X-axis from the function. I've spent several days trying to discover why this is the case, and eventually decided on just hacking around it.

So I want to get the rotation around the relative-x axis, transform the CameraRotation matrix, and then check it after to verify that it's the same, and if it isn't, add a correcting matrix.

Just for reference, I've seen some diagrams on Wikipedia, and I actually have a relatively strange axis layout, which is Y axis up, but X axis forwards and Z axis right, so Y axis yaw, Z axis pitch, X axis roll.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. 2D or 3D? And how does a matrix contain an axis?

Comment: It's a 3D matrix (4x4), and the matrix doesn't contain the axis, I have the axis. I want to know how far around this axis the matrix rotates.

Comment: @DeadMG 3D rotation matrices can be represented as 3x3 matrices. I still don't see a well defined problem here. It might help if you gave some background.

Comment: @David Heffernan In D3DX (and e.g XNA) transformations are done in 4x4 matrices for extra functionality/convenience.

Comment: @David: Ok. I have a matrix that defines a rotation. I'm going to give this matrix undefined other transformations. I need to verify (and, if necessary, correct) it at the end to ensure that it doesn't contain any additional rotations around a predetermined axis.

Comment: @DeadMG, so you want to be sure the matrix rotates around the axises around (0,0,0)?

Comment: @Caspar: No. I want to be sure that after transformation, it rotates around the X axis exactly as much as it did before transformation, but for any axis, not just X.

Comment: @DeadMG, aah, you want to be sure the rotationmatrix stays intact after transformation. Eg.When rotating a model of a helicopter you want to be sure the rotation of the rotors stays the same (eg 0,0,-1)? Correct?

Comment: @Caspar: Yes, something like that.

Comment: can you add some sample/elaboration, description of the behaviour and the solution you trying to find?

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle).
*Warning: Math ahead*